# Copy to clipboard in chrome extension V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, copy-paste

I am developing a chrome extension V3. I want to copy content to clipboard in my JS file. 
The manifest.json as below,

```
    "background" :{
        "service_worker" :"eventPage.js"
    },
    "permissions" : [
        "contextMenus",
        "clipboardWrite"      
    ]
```

I have try 2 solution for copy feature.

Solution 1:

```
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = str;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.left = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
```

The result:

```
Error in event handler: ReferenceError: document is not defined at copyToClipboard
```

Solution 2:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(str);
```

The result:

```
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText')
```

The chrome extension is run as a service worker. So it seems I can't access DOM document and have no grant of writeText. Does anyone have another suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to open a visible page with an html file of your extension and copy the text there.

Comment: So I can't implement that functionality in right click and contextMenus, right?

Comment: You'll have to a) open a visible page with an html file of your extension and copy the text there or b) declare/inject a content script into the active tab (or any tab with a web page) and copy the text there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll follow the excellent suggestion wOxxOm gave you, elaborating it in a concrete example. What you want to do is have a ContentScript.js that runs on any active tab with a web page, since you can't access the DOM from the backGround.js, and then send a message to this script, from where you would copy to the clipboard.

manifest.json

```
    "background" :{
        "service_worker" :"eventPage.js"
    },
    "permissions" : [
        "contextMenus",
        "clipboardWrite"      
    ],
   "content_scripts": [ // this is what you need to add
      {
         "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
         ],
         "js": ["content.js"]
      }
   ],
```

From the background.js, you would send a message, that will be handled in the ContentScript.js

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 
        {
            message: "copyText",
            textToCopy: "some text" 
        }, function(response) {})
})
```

In the contentScript.js, you would catch the message and copy it to the clipboard.

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( // this is the message listener
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "copyText")
            copyToTheClipboard(request.textToCopy);
    }
);

async function copyToTheClipboard(textToCopy){
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = textToCopy;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.left = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Through your sample code, I have solved the issue!

Comment: You're welcome! If it helped you, could you please mark the answer as accepted? It would help me and also other people to get to the solution quickly.

Comment: I keep getting the same error when I copy your code: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Comment: It means that when the background.js sends a message to the active tab via chrome.tabs.sendMessage, the content.js on the page is not ready or not reloaded.  Try reloading the page after you install the extension. Also, have you changed `eventPage.js` with `background.js` in your `manifest.json`? Double check the names of the files you created

Comment: Two details to add:
  * the provided solution indeed works for me but `document.execCommand('copy');`is deprecated and I cannot manage tomake Navigator.clipboard.writeText('') to work.
  * It is possible to inject the js dynamically with `chrome.scripting.executeScript(`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert in Chrome addons, but I believe that requesting `<all_urls>` is not best practice.
Instead, I got something to work by request [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/) instead, ditching the content scripts and injecting code to the active tab instead.
Manifest:

```
...
    "permissions": [
      "clipboardWrite"
      "activeTab",
      "scripting"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
...
```

Background:

```
// To be injected to the active tab
function contentCopy(text) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
}

async function copyLink(text, tab) {
  // Format as a whatsapp link
  const link = await getWhatsAppLink(text);
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: contentCopy,
    args: [link],
  });
}
```

So `contentCopy` is injected to the active tab and executed with the text I want to copy to clipboard.
Works well, and saves on problematic permissions (according to Google)

Comment: How do you get the active tab?

Comment: You can do const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        lastFocusedWindow: true,
      });