# How do I make a chrome extension copy data to the users clipboard?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, deployment

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that adds a context menu, which when pressed copies the highlighted text, link, image, etc.

This is the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/roll20-media-sender/lpmhjmhckammfiebfmimnjepibldfhjo and this is the github for the code: https://github.com/Rasul-583/Roll20-Media-Sender

I'm struggling with getting the app to actually copy the data. I keep getting the following error:

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText') at chrome-extension://jijdnkfbchnjlimcackdbdcnknnbjnlk/background.js:34:25.

The extension doesn't crash or anything, it "works" as in it launches and is generally functional, sending the notifications as intended. It just refuses to copy the data to the clipboard.

Here's the js script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( data => { // add a listener for incoming messages from the extension
  if ( data.type === 'notification' ) { // if the incoming message has a type of "notification"
    CBC( data.message ); // call a function CBC with the message from the data object as its argument
  }
});


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( () => { //code for context menu
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'CBC',
    title: "Create Beyond20 Command", 
    contexts:[ "selection", "link", "image", "video" ]
  });
});


chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener( ( info, tab ) => {//code for when context menu is pressed
  if ( 'CBC' === info.menuItemId ) {
    CBC( info.selectionText || info.linkUrl || info.srcUrl || 'error');
    navigator.clipboard.writeText( '[[after]]'+' [name]'+'('+info.selectionText+')[[/after]]'
    || '[[after]]'+' [name]'+'('+info.linkUrl+')[[/after]]'
    || '[[after]]'+' [name]'+'('+info.srcUrl+')[[/after]]' || 'error');
  }
} );


const CBC = message => { 
  return chrome.notifications.create( //code for notification system
    '',
    {
      type: 'basic',
      title: 'Command Created',
      message: '[[after]]'+' [name]'+'('+message+')[[/after]]' || 'error',
      iconUrl: './assets/icons/128.png',
    }
  );
};
```

I've searched for solutions extensively on the internet but haven't found much. I tried simply making a test website with the same code to see if my code was fundamentally flawed but it worked perfectly so I just assumed it didn't work because my extension wasn't approved and published on the chrome webstore yet. This was not correct as it still is non-functional after publishing. Might have something to do with the new manifest v3? Not sure, am still a newbie dev.

Comment: Service worker don't have a DOM so they can't access the clipboard.

Comment: Try [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71336017/20432796)

Comment: Use document.execCommand('copy') inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/), see the official example: [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.offscreen-clipboard-write).